# Loading the right url with anchors and jquery on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue when i'm loading the pages on my website. The main page has anchors since it's a one page, however i wanted to add a blog so i made it a two pages website. The url looks like mywebsite.com#content But now when I'm on the blog and I'm trying to get back to the main page, but the url loads like that : mywebsite.com/blog#content.

So i'd like the url to look like that : mywebsite.com/#content, but i don't know if that's possible...

Here is the html for the links :

```
<a href="#homepage" class="js-scrollTo"><li>Accueil</li></a>
        <a href="#projects" class="js-scrollTo"><li>Projets</li></a>
        <a href="#about" class="js-scrollTo"><li>A propos</li></a>
        <a href="#contact" class="js-scrollTo"><li>Contact</li></a>
        <a href="/blog"><li>Blog</li></a>
```

To make a smooth scroll effect on the main I used the following jquery :

```
var scroll = {
    scrollTo : function () {
        var page = $(this).attr('href'); // Target page
        var speed = 750; // Animation duration
        $('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: $(page).offset().top }, speed ); // Go
        return false;
    } // attribute scrollTo
}; // object scroll

$('.js-scrollTo').on('click', scroll.scrollTo);
```

Is there a way to make the url this way : mywebsite.com/#content and still have the scrolling effect with jquery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple use **e.preventDefault** instead of **return false**. Also, add a control to check if your "anchor page" exists in the dom.

Example with external page: **https://www.vixed.it/st/43002103**

Anyway I think is better to change the name of your function, can create a misunderstand with jQuery scroll and scrollTo.

Don't forget that **li** tags should contains the **a** and and not the opposite.

```js
var scroll = {
    scrollTo : function (e) {
      var page = $(this).attr('href');
      if ($('div.page'+page).length) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        var speed = 750; 
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(page).offset().top}, speed);
      } else {
        location.href='/'+page; //your home url + #page
      }
    }
};

$('.js-scrollTo').on('click', scroll.scrollTo);
```

```css
a{color:#09C}
.nav{
  list-style:none;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  width:100%;
  background:#000;
  margin:0;
  padding:5px 0;
}
.nav li{
  display:inline;
  margin:0 5px;
}
.page{
  min-height:200px;
  padding:35px;
  border:1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#homepage" class="js-scrollTo">Accueil</a></li>
  <li><a href="#projects" class="js-scrollTo">Projets</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about" class="js-scrollTo">A propos</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact" class="js-scrollTo">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="homepage" class="page">Accueil</div>
<div id="projects" class="page">Projets</div>
<div id="about" class="page">A propos</div>
<div id="contact" class="page">Contact</div>
<div style="height:1000px;">Footer</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry about the time it took me to anwser, i was out on work this week-end ! I tried your solution, it didn't work at all... The links don't work anymore when i'm on the blog page and the js gives the following error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.scrollTo (app.ec33c5a….js:106)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)

Comment: how can be possible? I mean.. it works on the snippet.

Comment: the snippet gives me a 404 on the blog page... The point is to be able to go back to the main page without giving this url : www.mywebsite.com/blog#contact when we click the contact or any of the links that points to the main page ! Right now it gives me the JS error when i click the links for the main page if i'm on the blog page !

Comment: yes I did, that's my whole problem, when i do /#url in the href, the js crashes because it doesn't recognize the /, it expects an id, and I have no idea how to change that

Comment: Can you show me a bit more of your code? and the main page url,,

Comment: I don't have much more code that uses the url, i'm starting to think that a one page just shouldn't have a second page and that I should make the blog on a second website and add it to the main site with a subdomain...

Comment: sorry again about the late answer ! Just tried your edited solution, it works like a charm, it's perfect ! :) And your solution is elegant, i love it, thank you so much !